# Is there an efficient way to fill in the elements of a matrix as m11,m12....etc?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I want to autofill the elements of a matrix (or list) by `m11`, `m12`, etc.

I am able to autofill using `Table[]` function however, I am not able to dot product using it.

Comment: Something like `Array[m, {3, 3}]`?

Comment: It somewhat works. What if I want it to be m_11 rather that m[1,1] that I am getting now (11 to be in subscript). Also I am not be to dot product with it.

Comment: If you look at the documentation for the `Subscript` function it provides a clear example of how to create an array whose elements look like `m_1,1` (where I use `_` to mean subscription).  As for the second part of your question, I just don't understand what it is you can't do.  Perhaps an illustrative example would help.

Comment: Please note though that `Subscript` is a **formatting** construction. For **calculations**, the idiomatic way is to use `m[i,j]`.

Answer (score 3):

```
Array[Subscript[m, FromDigits[{##}]] &, {3, 3}]
```

> $$
> \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  m_{11} & m_{12} & m_{13} \\
>  m_{21} & m_{22} & m_{23} \\
>  m_{31} & m_{32} & m_{33} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)
> $$

Comment: Thanks. I am also not able to dot product this matrix with column vector.

Comment: @ChetanWaghela please write down the command that doesn't work. I cannot debug it otherwise.

Comment: Only use the `Subscript` for display. `Clear["Global\`*"]; 

Format[m[j_, k_]] := Subscript[m, FromDigits[{j, k}]];
(mat = Array[m, {3, 3}]) // MatrixForm`

Comment: @BobHanlon there's nothing fundamentally wrong with working with subscripts. They are not the best idea, but also not something I'd vocally discourage. Adding a `Format` layer is, in my view, at least as confusing as assigning `DownValues` to `Subscript` instead of `OwnValues` to the subscripted symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps

```
Table[ToExpression["m" <> ToString[i] <> ToString[j]], {i, 1, 3}, {j,1, 3}]
(*{{m11, m12, m13}, {m21, m22, m23}, {m31, m32, m33}}*)
```

is what you are looking for? Here the `mij` are, in contrast to the `Subscript` version,  unique variables!